# Create REST or GRAPHQL API's In Shopify App and use it as third party in other software

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template

I am trying to create REST and GRAPHQL API's in the shopify app so that I could use it in my software. What I am trying to do is that whenever someone installs my app and subscribe to my software, I could use it store's data in my software. I know that it could happen by creating private app but I don't want to use it. I only want to use public app. How to achieve this? I tried by creating an API and call it from postman but in response it tells me that shop is not given. where to give shop name?